# after created alias directory service wamp not running

Tags: wampserver

I am using wamp server version 2.2

I have to create an alias name , but after alias created wamp servervice is not running it's turned yellow not blue..

what's wrong ?

```
Alias /Yudeth/ "D:/Yudeth/" 

<Directory "D:/Yudeth/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: Are you talking of virtual directory or what ... ?

Comment: Yes I want to create a vitual directory in wamp server but after created service wamp is not running..

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using wamp 2.2 you can create alias directly from system tray icon ..

see this [post](http://nothingtopost.wordpress.com/2010/10/07/how-to-create-an-alias-in-wamp/)

Comment: Yes i did but after created , Wamp service is not running it's turned yellow not blue ,I'm going to c:/wamp/alias/ i saw the vitual directory file **.conf file that i created it's stored there.